# ELB https health check with strict client auth

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, tls1.2, amazon-elb

I have an application running on AWS with strict mTLS. It is fronted by ELB. How do I run `https` ELB health check for my app? (of course, running https check will require client cert and key).

I am not sure ELB listeners is an option here. I really want to terminate tls at EC2 instance level.

Is there any other alternative here?

Comment: Added more specific and relevant tags.

Comment: Strict mTLS on an ELB seems impossible, except for two possibilities, specifically: using a Classic ELB and the balancer in TCP (not SSL) mode on front side and back... or using an NLB and not terminating TLS in the balancer.  Confirm which of these you are using, please? (Or mention another viable scenario if I have overlooked one.)

Comment: We created a dedicated URL path in our application for the load balancer health check to hit. The Health Check URL is unauthenticated.

Comment: @SangamBelose Thank for updating the tags.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I am currently using classic ELB to solve my problem. But I am open to switching to NLB as well. I have not looked into NLB yet, but If it is possible to solve the problem.

Comment: @myron-semack I did consider that path, but then for example, if there is something really wrong with https level, for example, let's say, Certificates are no longer valid. Of course, I can add a separate health check it.

Comment: @Payal The ELB health check does not validate certificates anyway. And even if your certificate WAS bad, you probably don’t want that to be a health check failure, as that will terminate your instances and bring down the site. (Doing too much in a health check is a common mistake.)

Comment: @myron-semack If I have a https health check which is simply doing 200 OK check on index.html on the server side and if server-side tls cert is expired on the server side. My health check will right away. I totally agree, having too much in a health check is not the right way to go here.  I will also look into creating a URL path which is unauthenticated.